# Efficiently evaluating an index mapping function in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu, gpu

In a CUDA kernel I need to find a key which is mapped to the threadIdx.

The mapping can look like this:

> key -> threadIdx
>
> 0 -> {0,1,2,3,4}
>
> 1 -> {5,6,7}
>
> 2 -> {8,9,10}
>
> ...

Each key `k_i` is mapped to `n_i` (varying, arbitrary `n_i` with `n_i>0` ) threads.
The key will be used to retrieve the corresponding value in a global array. This value is then used in the subsequent calculations in this kernel.

The mapping can be plotted as a piecewise constant function:

[image: example of mapping function]

The number of keys is not limited to 3 (this is only an example!) and only known at runtime, as well as respective "width" of each key.

How can I **efficiently** find out the corresponding key in the CUDA kernel?
I thought of the following two alternatives:

1. using a binary search inside the kernel (memory efficient)
2. precomputing the mapping for each threadIDx, then launching the kernel (runtime efficient)

   > 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It is likely more efficient to read each element once (into shared memory). Although the cache will help you when hitting the same addresses repeatedly, shared memory is likely to be much better for a large number of reads. If there are roughly even numbers of values per key, then it is likely better to let each thread handle all values for its key.

Comment: Your mapping seems to be simply `int key = ((int)threadIdx.x-2) / 3;` which can easily and efficiently be computed by every thread on the fly. If the divisor is a run-time variable rather than a template parameter this would require a full 32-bit integer division, but it should still be quite efficient. Have you tried and timed it?

Comment: @njuffa As I pointed out above: Each "width" can be different!

Comment: @m.s. It was not clear to me what that exactly that meant. I took it to mean that the "width" is different, but a linear function of the number of keys, as suggested by your example [a step function with a constant "slope"]. In which case a formula based on integer division should work. Are you saying the "width" is completely arbitrary, i.e. it cannot be described by a closed-form expression that could be evaluated at run time by every thread?

Comment: @njuffa yes the "width" is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another algorithm that gives you something median in terms of memory- and runtime-efficiency:
Assume the total number of threads is `N`. Let's take number `M` that is close to `sqrt(N)` and divide all threads into groups by `M` thread each (the last one will be incomplete). Now, precalculate key only for first thread in each group (their idxes will be `0`, `M`, `2M` and so on). It gives us `O(sqrt(N))` memory asymptotics.
Now, in kernel, we can easily find index of current group (`groupIdx = threadIdx / M`) and next group (`groupIdx + 1`). For each of them we know pre-calculated keys `key[groupIdx]` and `key[groupIdx + 1]`. Now you can do BS, but take `[key[groupIdx]; key[groupIdx + 1]]` segment for search instead of `[1; MAX_KEY_VALUES]`.

Comment: How is the complexity of this algorithm compared to traditional binary search?

Comment: It's hard to estimate, because it depends on key-thread distribution, but, something like `O(log_2(MAX_KEY_VALUE/sqrt(N)))` instead of `O(log_2(MAX_KEY_VALUE))` for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine - every thread, when it starts, find it's own key with BS and store it in array.

Comment: Please see my edit, the goal is not only to find the key but the key is used to retrieve the correct memory location for further calculations. So I do not need to store the keys, I only need them temporarily in the kernel.